# How to "scheduleInRunLoop" for multiple TCP Connection Stream in iOS?

Tags: ios, multithreading, tcpclient, nsstream

I have a main TCP connection on port 3001. I wanna open another connection on port 3002 for file upload and download.

I can open the second connection however; app crashes on following piece of code:

```
self.inputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
self.outputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
```

I think it's because main tcp connection has a "scheduleInRunLoop", second one causes app to crash.

How to scheduleInRunLoop for my second connection?